# How to evaluate machine learning model performance on brand new datasets, in addition to train, validation, and test datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, model, metrics

**The Scenario:**
Our data science team builds machine learning models for classification tasks. We evaluate our model performance on train, validation and test datasets. We use precision, recall and F1 score.
We then run the models on brand-new datasets in the production environment and make predictions. One week later, we get feedback on how well our predictive models have performed.

**The question:**
When we evaluate the performance of our models on the real datasets, what metrics should we use? Is prediction accuracy a better metric in this context?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should either measure the same metrics, or some business metrics.

Usually the models are optimized for a certain loss/metric and this means that model having a high value of a certain metric can have a worse value on a different metric.

Accuracy is a metric which is heavily influenced by balance of classes in the data, so it should be used with care.

So I suggest to use the same metrics.

Another approach is using some business metrics - for example the revenue, which these models brought.

Comment: How do we differentiate the recall/precision produced from test dataset and the precision/recall produced from real dataset from production environment?

Comment: Well, they are calculated on separate datasets, right? So they will be different. If you need some interpretation: "usual" test dataset is an unseen data which is actual for the current moment. "Production" test dataset shows new data, which will arrive in future. Usually this new data could change with time, so it would be necessary to periodically retrain the model to improve performance.

Comment: @camel. compare your results with actual outcomes of business you can get that metrics

Answer (score 0):

## Model evaluation

Take a look at [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.nic.2020.08.004). It is fairly easy to follow and covers everything you need to know about machine learning model validation.